# Transactional messages without receiver look - session peeking

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, servicebus

I have a distributed service that takes anywhere from 10 sec to 10 min to process a message. The service starts on a user's (== browser) request which is received through an API. Due to various limitations, the result of the service has to be returned outside of the initial request (timeouts, dropped client connections ...) Therefore I return a SessionId to the requesting user which can be used to retrieve the result until it expires.

Now it can happen that a user makes multiple consecutive requests for the result while the session is still locked. For example the following code gets hit with the same SessionId within 60 seconds:

```
var session = await responseQueue.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(sessionId);
var response = await session.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
if (response == null)
{
    session.Abort();
    return null;
}
await response.AbandonAsync();
```

What I need is a setup without locking and the ability to read a message multiple times until it expires plus the ability to wait for yet non-existent messages.

Which ServiceBus solution fits that bill?

**UPDATE**

Here's a dirty solution, still looking for a better way:

```
MessageSession session = null;

try
{
    session = await responseQueue.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(sessionId);
}
catch
{
    // ... and client has to try again until the 60 sec lock from other requests is released
}

var response = await session.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
// ...
```